# Removing index.php in CodeIgniter using .htaccess file when using your own local domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have seen other articles on the same issue. But none of the answers have solved my problem.

I am not using xampp or wamp but have setup php mysql apache seperately. Also I am using my own local domain for instance mytestsite.com.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /TestCI/

    # Canonicalize Codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(HomeController(/index)?|index(\.php|html?)?)/?$ / [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|TestCI) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mytestsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

I have also made following changes in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mytestsite.com/TestCI/';    
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'; //AUTO
```

I have also made following changes in apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But when i try to access

```
http://mytestsite.com/TestCI/HomeController/
```

its showing 404 error but works correctly when using

```
http://mytestsite.com/TestCI/index.php/HomeController/
```

I have looked into several similar questions that have been reported solved, but none of the answers have worked for me. Is there anything else that should be done to remove `index.php` from the url. Kindly respond back. Help highly appreciated.

Comment: Try my code may be it help...

Comment: still showing Not found error
The requested URL /var/www/mytestsite.com/public_html/TestCI/index.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the htaccess isn't being used.

Put a sytax error in the file. (Append something like hdtbf to the file)

If that doesn't give a 500 error you need to turn `allow override all`
In your main Apache config

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I have already made changes in allow override all. Its still same

Comment: did you restart the server ?

Comment: And it did give an internal server error when I made syntax mistake in .htaccess file. I still cant find what the issue is

Comment: Yes restarted the server several times. After making all those changes. but it just dont work without index.php in the url.

Comment: still showing Not found error
The requested URL /var/www/mytestsite.com/public_html/TestCI/index.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line of code in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Have made the changes, but still no success

Comment: I have changed my answer, check once now

Comment: Still same. .htaccess file now looks like <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /TestCI/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php 
</IfModule>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91197/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-eccentriccoder).

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code in your .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can u please explain RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)

Comment: still showing Not found error
The requested URL /var/www/mytestsite.com/public_html/TestCI/index.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for helping me... Problem is solved.

I made the following changes in my apache2.conf file

```
<Directory /Absolute path to .htaccess folder

        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also I removed the RewriteBase parameter in .htaccess file which is where the actual pbm was.

My current .htaccess file looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On


    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php 
</IfModule>
```

I have also made changes in config.php where i changed $config['base_url'] to codeigniter root path